# Complex Analysis analytic function problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ ang $g$ are two analytic functions on the set $\Bbb C$ of all complex numbers with $f(1/n) = g(1/n)$ for $n= 1,2,3,\ldots$, then show that $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$.

Comment: Use Identity theorem.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $f(z)-g(z)=0$ on a set of points with a limit point.